# Permission error when trying to install ZeroMQ package with npm

Tags: npm, permissions, zeromq

I'm trying to install the `zeromq` library on my Mac running on ARM64, which I need to use node-red, and am getting a permission error. I get this error when trying to install the latest version using npm.

```
josiahkievit@Josiahs-MacBook-Pro ~ % npm install zeromq@6.0.0-beta.17
npm ERR! code 126
npm ERR! path /Users/josiahkievit/node_modules/zeromq
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c (shx test -f ./script/build.js || run-s build.js) && cross-env npm_config_build_from_source=true node-gyp-build
npm ERR! sh: /Users/josiahkievit/node_modules/.bin/cross-env: Permission denied
```

Before installing this, I used brew to install `cmake` and `zeromq` which were required.

I'm not sure if this issue is specifically related to the package not having support for ARM64 architecture. In general, though, if anyone has insight regarding the 126 error code in this type of situation, that would be great. I also did try using sudo, and that didn't work either.